# Upload content to Apple TV

Tags: appletv, data-transfer

Is that possible to upload some videos from my macbook (itunes library) to apple tv? This way, I can watch that movies without use my macbook or any kind of streaming.

Answer (score 1):

Depends on which AppleTV you have.

With the 1st generation you can select which videos from your media library to sync with and iTunes would copy them to the AppleTV.

Unfortunately the 2nd generation doesn't have any internal storage, so it can only stream videos.

Comment: @RobZolkos ok, but in iTunes I don't have Device List either Apple TV on it, but I can stream content to it.

Comment: Do you have the new AppleTV or the older one with internal hard drive?

Comment: I have a new one, black. I bought it last week in Apple Store at Las Vegas.

Comment: You won't be able to sync to it. It has no internal storage.

Comment: The 2nd generation does have internal storage (8 GB). It is used as a cache during streaming. Unfortunately Apple doesn't allow you to store content there for other purposes.